# Maintain button forecolor when disabled

Tags: vb.net, button, disabled-control

I have a button in my winform app.The problem is that when i disable the button, the forecolor becomes Green-ish.Is there a way to keep the forecolor Black even when it's disabled ??? I tried numerous solutions from past SO questions, googled for quiet some time now.But the solutions are either in c#(i converted them but still no luck) or to create a custom button control. Any solution?

Comment: Create your own, you can inherit the existing control... Look into the paint event.

Comment: Can you please explain ? @Codexer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.net|| keep button color unchanged when it is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610460/vb-net-keep-button-color-unchanged-when-it-is-disabled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. The reason the button does not take `.ForColor` assignments (if I am not mistaken) has to do with the background events that are redrawing and repainting it. I haven't gotten all the way down to the "nitty-gritty" but the gist I got was that (as far as I've found so far) the only way to address the color is in the paint event.

Basically, you can handle the color change in an Extension and rather than using `Button.Enabled = False` you call it like this:

```
btnNext.Enable
btnPrevious.Disable
```

All you need to do is add a module (below) to your project and all buttons will have the `.Enable` and `.Disable` Extension.

**HERE'S THE MODULE:**

```vb
Module Extensions
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Sub Enable(ByVal btn As Button)
        If btn.Tag = Nothing Then ' << This ensures we only add the handler once.
            AddHandler btn.EnabledChanged, AddressOf btn_EnabledChanged
            AddHandler btn.Paint, AddressOf btn_Paint
        End If
        btn.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Sub Disable(ByVal btn As Button)
        If btn.Tag = Nothing Then ' << This ensures we only add the handler once.
            AddHandler btn.EnabledChanged, AddressOf btn_EnabledChanged
            AddHandler btn.Paint, AddressOf btn_Paint
        End If
        btn.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_EnabledChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        If sender.enabled = False Then
            btn.ForeColor = Color.Black
        Else
            btn.ForeColor = Color.Black
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        'Dim TextForBtn As String = ""  ' << we don't use a variable because that would only be useful if we could reassign to the .Text property, but that just raises the Paint Event again causing a infinite loop.
        Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        If btn.Text > " " Then
            btn.Tag = btn.Text ' << this allows us to redraw the text, the one issue however is the .Text property is empty from here on out.
            'TextForBtn = btn.Text ' << this is part of the failed idea of using a variable and reassigning to the .Text property.
        End If
        btn.Text = String.Empty ' << make sure Text is not written on button as well as rendered below
        Dim flags As TextFormatFlags = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter Or TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter Or TextFormatFlags.WordBreak  'center the text
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, btn.Tag.ToString, btn.Font, e.ClipRectangle, btn.ForeColor, flags) ' << TextForBtn was replaced with btn.Tag.ToString in the second parameter
        'btn.Text = TextForBtn ' << this caused an infinite loop necessitating the use of the .Tag property.
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: @Aousafrashid CODE EDIT: I realized I was adding the Handler each time ```.Disable``` was called (adding the same handler to potentially the same button multiple times) and I was not adding the handlers for ```.Enable```. The code should not have those issues now.